# How can I pass arguments to my python script in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create button to run my python script for users. Script takes few arguments from user. How can I pass these arguments to the script?

````
import os
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()

window.title("Configure clients")
window.geometry('550x200')

def run():
    os.system('python create_client.py')

btn = Button(window, text="Click Me", bg="black", fg="white",command=run)
btn.grid(column=0, row=0)

window.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Did you try `os.system('python create_client.py arg1 arg2 ...')`? It depends on the logic inside `create_client.py`.

Comment: I tried os.system('python create_client.py arg1 arg2 ...') with hard coded argument then it works but when I add entry.get () then it dosen't work.

Comment: You can use *f-strung*: `os.system(f'python create_client.py {entry.get()} ...')`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `os.system`, you should use `subprocess.Popen`.

Because `os.system` waits for the command to complete, it will make your launcher GUI unresponsive.

When you use `subprocess.Popen` it will start a new process, but it will not wait for it to end.

The first argument to the `Popen` constructor should be a sequence of arguments, like:

```
args = ["python", "create_client.py", "arg1", "arg2"]
```

You could get the arguments from `Entry` widgets.

I would propose to call `Popen` as follows:

```
import subprocess as sp

p = sp.Popen(
    ["python", "create_client.py", "arg1", "arg2"], 
    stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, text=True
)
```

Save the `Popen` instance in a list, because you might want to do things with it later.
For example, you might want to check the eventual return value of the process. If the process exits with an error, you might want to show the standard output and/or standard error to the user.
That is also the reason for supplying `sp.PIPE` to `stdout` and `stderr`; it saves the output of the program.

Read the `subprocess` documentation. It contains much more information then can be given in an answer.